# VHDL Synthesis Warning

Tags: vhdl, warnings

I don't know what is my problem , I got warning 
I have no problem with syntax but I want to know how to assign input value to scroll . 
Thanks.

```
WARNING:Xst:1895 - Due to other FF/Latch trimming, FF/Latch <msg_array_59> (without init value) has a constant value of 1 in block <ShifterAMZ>. This FF/Latch will be trimmed during the optimization process.
```

I'm trying to do 7 segment scrolling .. Any Help Please!

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity ShifterAMZ is
    Port ( clr : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           q : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0));
end ShifterAMZ;

architecture Behavioral of ShifterAMZ is

signal msg_array: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 TO 63);
Constant STD_ID : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (63 DOWNTO 0) :=X"2016115362016115";


begin

    PROCESS (clk)
        begin
            if clk'event and clk ='1' then
                if clr='1' then
                    msg_array <= STD_ID;
                else
                msg_array(0 to 59) <= msg_array (4 to 63);
                msg_array(60 to 63) <= msg_array (0 to 3);
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
        q <= msg_array(0 to 15);

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: It looks like there are more warnings contributing to this. Can you copy in more of the warning output?

Comment: try to initialize `msg_array`:
`signal msg_array: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (0 TO 63) := (other => '0')`;

Comment: The VHDL standard has no warnings. Perhaps you could include a tag for the particular synthesis tool vendor.